# array con chart.js , javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy utilizando Chart.js con ella muestro una gráfica donde mostrare monto y transacciones de una cuenta eso incluye que debe tener su fechas  y  la transacciones q hicieron esa fecha, es decir esa variables vienen en array, pero no se como aplicarlas dejare abajo algo del código construido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//intente hacer el array pero no me salio esta parte del código no funciona

```
this.listTrans=[];
        this.listTrans=[{
            fecha:'2018-08-01',
            amount:200000,
            count:3,
            formatted_amount=2000,00;
        },{
            fecha:'2018-08-02',
            amount:500000,
            count:8,
            formatted_amount=5000,00;
        }]

        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < listTrans.length; i++){
            list += listTrans[i]; 
            list[i].hasOwnProperty('amount'){
            var amount  mes.push(list[i].amount);
            }
```

//esta parte si funciona pero no como yo quiero  estas variables tienen valores  pero quiero que me venga en array de la parte de arriba y se muestre en la gráfica

```
var mes = ["01/02/18","01/03/18","01/03/18"]; //esto quiero que me venga en array 
var amount = [1000,2000,2500];// esto serian los valores que incluiria el rray
var  count = [5,6,3];// igualmente este..


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: mes,
    datasets: [
      { 
        data: amount,
        label: "Monto",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      },
      { 
        data: count,
        label: "Transacciones",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      }

    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Revisa la sintaxis. Los separadores del array de arriba deben ser puntos, no comas, al final de cada elemento del arreglo no puede ir punto y coma. formatted_amount=2000,00; => formatted_amount=2000.00;

Comment: sii cierto debe ser que no lo vi pero igual no funciona ..

Comment: tienes algun ejemplo en jsfiddle ?

Comment: no aun no .....

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pt6mhwuq/6/

Comment: listo, ejemplo agregado, puedes verlo en jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He modificado el array de objetos para que sea válido, pero entiendo que necesitas algo como esto:

```js
var listTrans=[{
            fecha:'2018-08-01',
            amount:'200000',
            count:'3',
            //formatted_amount='2000,00'
        },{
            fecha:'2018-08-02',
            amount:'500000',
            count:'8',
            //formatted_amount='5000,00'
        }]

        var mes = []
        var amount = [];
        var  count = []; 


        listTrans.map(o=>{
          mes.push(o.fecha)
          amount.push(o.amount)
          count.push(o.count);
        })

        console.log(mes)
        console.log(amount)
        console.log(count)
```

Modificando el ejemplo que envías de fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5pek4r0x/1/

Comment: esoo mismoo! .. gracias  es lo que necesito

Answer (score 0):

Podrias asociar los ID en el eje vertical:

```
var mes = ["01/02/18","01/03/18","01/03/18"];
var amount = [1000,2000,2500];
var  transacciones = [5,6,3];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
    scales: {
       xAxes: [ {}, {} ],
         yAxes: [{ 
            id: "y-monto" 
       }, { 
          id: "y-transacciones"
       }]
    }
  },
  data: {
    labels : mes,
    datasets: [
      { 
        data: amount,
        label: "Monto",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false,
        yAxisID: 'y-monto'
      },
      { 
        data: transacciones,
        label: "Transacciones",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false,
        yAxisID: 'y-transacciones'
      }

    ]
  } 
});
```

Ejemplo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/cardeol/3h9mub10/1/)